# Laravel Multi Database Errors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

All,

I am currently testing out some rather interesting software for Laravel. [Backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/) is a CRUD based do-it-yourself admin panel that I am fooling around with to possible integrate for a later project. I am however having some trouble filling databases correctly when I migrate. For example, I was trying to install the user permission package (the software works in blocks so you install the base then add packages) and everything goes well until I migrate into my database when it gives me an error like this:

```
    [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
  already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null  
  auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null,
  `email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null,  
  `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate ut
  f8mb4_unicode_ci)



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'    
  already exists



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'  
  already exists
```

I know that is is saying that I already have the tables created in the database (from the base package including an authentication function) but it doesn't make sense why they would be the same because they are different packages.  So I am wondering why this is happening; maybe I set something up wrong? Anything is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

[Backpack Github](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack)

Comment: Thanks; I'm trying to install the Permissions Manager module and for migrations I'm only using one as far as I know. That's why I'm confused :)

Comment: Im using the `Laravel new projectname` command in terminal as usual. And yes I only have one.